# Theorem related to the zeros of a function (Stein's Complex Analysis textbook)

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't understand some parts of a proof I've read on Stein's Complex Analysis. It's related to the  zeros of functions. I'll write the theorem, the proof and finally I'll ask my questions.

**Theorem** Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in a connected open set $\Omega$, has a zero at a point $z_0 \in \Omega$, and does not vanish identically in $\Omega$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U \subset \Omega$ of $z_0$, a non-vanishing holomorphic function $g$ on $U$, and a unique positive integer $n$ such that $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z) \space \space \forall z \in U$$

**Proof** Since $\Omega$ is connected and $f$ is not identically zero, we conclude that $f$ is not identically zero in a neighborhood of $z_0$. In a small disc centered at $z_0$ the function $f$ has a series power expansion $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k(z-z_0)^k$$
Since $f$ is not identically zero near $z_0$, there exists a smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a_n \neq 0$. Then, we can write $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^n[a_n+a_{n+1}(z-z_0)+...]=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$$
where $g$ is defined by the series in brackets, and hence is holomorphic, and is nowhere vanishing for all $z$ close to $z_0$ (since $a_n \neq 0$). To prove the uniqueness of the integer $n$, suppose that we can also write $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)=(z-z_0)^mh(z)$$

where $h(z_0) \neq 0$. If $m>n$, then we may divide by $(z-z_0)^n$ to see that $$g(z)=(z-z_0)^{m-n}h(z)$$

and letting $z \to z_0$ yields $g(z_0)=0$, a contradiction. If $m<n$ a similar argument gives $h(z_0)=0$, which is also a contradiction. We conclude that $m=n$, thus $h=g$, and the theorem is proved.

**My doubts** 
**1)** Does the statement $f(z_=0)=0$, and does not vanish identically in $\Omega$ means that $z_0$ is the only point of $\Omega$ where $f$ vanishes?

**2)** Why is in the theorem's statement said "a connected open set"? Isn't "connected open" a redundancy since all connected sets are open by definition? I am not trying to be fussy about words here, I am asking in case there is something I'm missing.

**3)** I have a doubt regarding the statement "...where $g$ is defined by the series in brackets, and hence is holomorphic, and is nowhere vanishing for all $z$ close to $z_0$ (since $a_n \neq 0$)... If I'm not mistaken, he says that $g$ is nowhere vanishing for all $z$ close to $z_0$ just because $a_n \neq 0$. Couldn't be the case that for some $z$ close to $z_0$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n+k}(z-z_0)^k=-a_n$ and so $g(z)=0$?

I understand that $g(z_0) \neq 0$ because $a_n \neq 0$, but for $z \neq z_0$ and close to $z_0$ wouldn't the correct argument be that if $g(z)=0 \implies f(z)=0$, and this is a contradiction since $z_0$ is the only point of $\Omega$ where $f$ vanishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) No, it means there are points where $f$ does not vanish.

(2) Connected sets need not be open: A line segment is connected, but not open. (It *could* be that Stein only defines connectedness for open sets, but the concept does make sense for non-open sets as well – although it gets a bit more complicated, as there are different concepts of connectedness to consider.)

(3) $g$ is continuous, and so $g(z_0)\ne0$ implies $g(z)\ne0$ for all $z$ sufficiently close to $z_0$. (Apply the definition of continuity with $\varepsilon=|g(z_0)|$ to see this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have doubts with (2), according to wikipedia the condition "$X$ is connected" is equivalent to the condition "The only subsets of $X$ which are clopen sets (both closed and open) are $X$ and the empty set. I think I got confused with these conditions, so, being connected doesn't mean necesarilly for a set $X$ to be open, it just means that if it existed a subset both open and closed, it would have to be $X$ or the empty set, is now my interpretation correct?

Comment: That's right, but note that when $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, you need to take “open” and “closed” as being relative to the subspace topology of $\Omega$. For a very simple example, let $D_1(z)$ be the open unit disk centered at $z$, and $\Omega=D_1(0)\cup D_1(2)$. Then $D_1(0)$ is open and closed as a subset of $\Omega$, although it is not closed in $\mathbb{C}$. For open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, connectedness is equivalent to *path connectedness*: That any two points in the set can be joined by a path in the set.